# How to modularize large js file with JQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I currently have one js file that serves all the html scripts, that is starting to become tedious.

It looks like this:

```js
// Using .html in jQuery big NO NO: https://medium.com/@jenlindner22/the-risk-of-innerhtml-3981253fe217, switched to .text

// Chart Variables
var teamProgressChart

// Get initial value from filters in /table
var seasonSelection = $('#seasonToggle').children(":first").val()
var typeSelection = $('#homeAwayToggle').children(":first").val()
var MatchweekSelection = $('#homeAwayToggle').children(":first").val()
// var leagueTableUpdateTimeStamp = 0

/**
 * Team progress chart update in /table
 */
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
    const teamVal = $(this).attr('value')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/table/team?' + $.param({ teamId: teamVal }),
        success: (res) => {
            var result = res[0]
            var points = result.pointsAll
            var position = result.positionAll
            var labels = result.gameweeks
            console.log(points)
            console.log(position)
            console.log(labels)
            if (teamProgressChart) {
                teamProgressChart.data.labels = labels
                teamProgressChart.data.datasets[0].data = points
                teamProgressChart.data.datasets[1].data = position
                teamProgressChart.update()
              } else {
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('team-progress-graph').getContext('2d');
                    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 24;
                    teamProgressChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: "Points",
                                    fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    pointColor: "rgba(200,122,20,1)",
                                    borderColor: "rgba(43, 87, 29, 0.9)",
                                    fill: false,
            
                                    data: points,
                                    yAxisID: 'points'
                                },
                                {
                                    label: "Position",
                                    fillColor: "rgba(172, 26, 26, 0.9)",
                                    strokeColor: "rgba(172, 26, 26, 0.9)",
                                    pointColor: "rgba(172, 26, 26, 0.9)",
                                    borderColor: "rgba(14, 86, 168, 0.9)",   
                                    fill: false,
            
                                    data: position,
                                    yAxisID: 'position'
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                xAxes: [
                                    {
                                        ticks: {
                                            fontSize: 24,
                                            autoSkip: false,
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                }
                                ],
                                yAxes: [
                                    {
                                        id: 'points',
                                        min: 0,
                                        position: 'left',
                                        ticks: {
                                            fontSize: 24,
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 'position',
                                        suggestedMin : 0,
                                        suggestedMax : 20,
                                        position: 'right', 
                                        ticks: {
                                            fontSize: 24
                                        }
                                    },
                                    
                                ]
                            },
                            display: false,
                        },
                    })
                }
        }
    })
})
                



/**
 * Button to updata data in /table
 */
$('#updateDataButton').bind('click', function(event){
    console.log(event.timeStamp)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/table',
        success: () => {
            console.log('success')
            window.location = "/";
        }
        
    })
});

/**
 * Click eventlistner for home-page player stats
 */
const homeTable = document.querySelectorAll(".stats-item");
homeTable.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', homeTableToggle)
})
function homeTableToggle(event){
    var queryVal = event.target.value
    console.log(queryVal)
    if (queryVal == 1){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/?' + $.param({ statsType: queryVal}),
            success: (newVals) => {   
                $('#stats-placehld').text("AvgPlayTime")
                $('#stats-placehld1').text("AvgPasses")
                console.log($('#stats-placehld1').textContent)
                $('#playerStatsAvg').empty();
                for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    let filteredTr = newVals[i]
                    let newHtml = `<tr>
                    <td>${filteredTr.name}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.teamName}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.position}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.averagePlaytime}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.averagePasses}</td>
                    </tr>`
    
                    $('#playerStatsAvg').append(newHtml)
                }
            }
        })
    } else if (queryVal == 2){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/?' + $.param({ statsType: queryVal}),
            success: (newVals) => {     
                $('#stats-placehld').text("AvgShots")
                $('#stats-placehld1').text("AvgOnTarget")  
                $('#playerStatsAvg').empty();
                for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    let filteredTr = newVals[i]
                    let newHtml = `<tr>
                    <td>${filteredTr.name}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.teamName}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.position}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.averageShotsPerGame}</td>
                    <td>${filteredTr.averageShotsOnTarget}</td>
                    </tr>`
    
                    $('#playerStatsAvg').append(newHtml)
                }
            }
        })
    }

}


//Click eventlistner for all table-filters
const selection = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item");
selection.forEach(element => {
   element.addEventListener('click', pickSelection)
})
function pickSelection(event) {
    let text = ""
    switch(event.target.parentElement.id){
        case 'seasonToggle':
            text = event.target.textContent
            $('#seasonvalue').text(text)
            seasonSelection =  event.target.value
            break
        case 'homeAwayToggle':
            text = event.target.textContent
            $('#typevalue').text(text)
            typeSelection =  event.target.value
            break
        case 'matchWeekToggle':
            text = event.target.textContent
            $('#matchDropDownMenyButton').text(text)
            MatchweekSelection =  event.target.value
            break
    }
    //Get request for
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/table?' + $.param({ seasonVal: seasonSelection, 
                                typeVal: typeSelection,
                                matchWeekVal: MatchweekSelection}),
   success: (filteredSeasonValues) => {          
            $('#league-table-rows').empty();
            for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                let filteredTr = filteredSeasonValues[i]
                let newHtml = `<tr>
                <td>${i+1}</td>
                <td><img src='badges/${filteredTr.team_shortName}.png' />
                ${filteredTr.team_shortName}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.played}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.won}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.drawn}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.lost}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.goalsFor}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.goalsAgainst}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.goalsDifference}</td>
                <td>${filteredTr.points}</td>
                </tr>`

                $('#league-table-rows').append(newHtml)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

How would one go about splitting it into multiple files, let's say page specific and importing them to a global js-file that later gets served, so the structure looks like this?

`home.js`

```js
//home specific jquery functions
```

`table.js`

```js
//table specific jquery functions
```

`client.js`

```js
import home.js
import table.js
```

index.html

```html
<script src="js/client.js" defer ></script>
```

Comment: You don't need to import anything, just include multiple `<script>`s in the correct order. (if script B needs to reference script A, put script A first)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for the input! How about when splitting it on widget-level/componet-level then there will be many `<script>` tags, is that still the go-to solution?

Comment: That depends; you probably shouldn't use dozens of scripts, no. But four or five of them is perfectly fine. If you find that you're going in the direction of having tons of components and therefore lots of small scripts, consider using webpack and import/export instead.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, will look into webpack!